# Unable to create Kafka topic or list topics

Tags: apache-kafka

I am facing issue when trying to run any command for kafka (list, create).
Getting error - Error while executing topic command : Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: listTopics

Execution command - `bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --topic quickstart-events --bootstrap-server localhost:9096`

Following are the required details:
Environment - RHEL8
Version of kafka- 3.1.0

Snippet from server.properties listener settings:

```
############################# Server Basics #############################

# The id of the broker. This must be set to a unique integer for each broker.
broker.id=17

# Switch to enable topic deletion or not, default value is false
delete.topic.enable=true

############################# Socket Server Settings #############################

# The address the socket server listens on. It will get the value returned from
# java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName() if not configured.
#   FORMAT:
#     listeners = listener_name://host_name:port
#   EXAMPLE:
#     listeners = PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092
listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9096

# Hostname and port the broker will advertise to producers and consumers. If not set,
# it uses the value for "listeners" if configured.  Otherwise, it will use the value
# returned from java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName().
#advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092

# Maps listener names to security protocols, the default is for them to be the same. See the config documentation for more details
#listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL
#listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT
```

Zookeeper configuration snippet:

```
############################# Zookeeper #############################

# Zookeeper connection string (see zookeeper docs for details).
# This is a comma separated host:port pairs, each corresponding to a zk
# server. e.g. "127.0.0.1:3000,127.0.0.1:3001,127.0.0.1:3002".
# You can also append an optional chroot string to the urls to specify the
# root directory for all kafka znodes.
zookeeper.connect=x.x.x.x:2181

# Timeout in ms for connecting to zookeeper
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=60000
```

Zookeeper is running on a different server(in the same network) and I can see in the logs that connection is successfully established.
Please let me know what am I missing here.

Verified zookeeper connection, verified that kafka is running on port 9096.
Broker is also listed in the logs.